# How to stack notifications on Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

following [my previous notification problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988073/why-does-jelly-bean-dont-show-the-second-row-in-a-notification) I wanted to test the new notification stack feature of Jelly Bean 4.1 as it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). I already found out, that notifications need to have different IDs, otherwise the older notification will just be updated with the content of the second notification. If I use different IDs, my Notifications will just be a list:

[image: Notification List]

The small secondary icon is set with setSmallIcon() (see my first notification on the screenshot above), while the larger icon is set with setLargeIcon(). What I cannot control is when the number of pending notifications will be displayed. It is not controlled by the [text lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988073/why-does-jelly-bean-dont-show-the-second-row-in-a-notification) mentioned in my other question.

So my guess is, that Jelly Bean will take care automatically of multiple notifications, but how can I trigger this? Maybe someone can give me a piece of code or a hint in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the answer in your question: "otherwise the older notification will just be updated with the content of the second notification". However, your app needs to have the smarts to know what the "second notification" should show, to cover all events since the last time the user interacted with your app. Then, the "second notification" can contain information about both events, not just the second one.

Comment: OK, so I need to keep track of displayed notifications with the FragmentManager? What about the Number Pending in the lower right corner next to the small icon? Is it part of the summary text or is it a custom layout? see ![Number Pending in the Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/media/notifications_pattern_additional_win.png).

Comment: @MarkusRudel: "so I need to keep track of displayed notifications with the FragmentManager?" -- I am not sure where `FragmentManager` plays a role here. "What about the Number Pending in the lower right corner next to the small icon?" -- in theory, that is the `setNumber()` value in your `Builder`. In practice, that number does not show up on all devices.

Comment: Oh damn, I've meant NotificationManager. Must be the heat. That must be also why I've overseen all the time setNumber(). So The app hast to take care of the number of unread events and fires just an update for eventually existing Notifications or it will show a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same notification id for all notifications and then just update the every notification with a new static number.